# Error while calling java stored procedure in oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jar

I have created a RunnableJar (a jar containing other third party jars like iText.jar, java classes, etc...) and I have upload that RunnableJar.jar in Oracle database using `loadjava`. In the jar i have main class `GetOffer` in that i have one `public String getOffer(String param1) { }` method and the use of this method is to create multiple pdf according to user selection and concat them.

Now I have created Stored procedure:

```
create or replace function getOffer(param1 in varchar2) return varchar2
    is language java name 'GetOffer.getOffer(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

And I have called this stored procedure using following call statement:

```
SQL> VARIABLE  myString  VARCHAR2(20);
SQL> CALL getOffer("XYZ") INTO :myString
```

When calling the procedure I am getting the below error:

```
SQL> VARIABLE  myString  VARCHAR2(20);
SQL> CALL getOffer("XYZ") INTO :myString
 2  ;
CALL getOffer("Any String") INTO :myString
 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is creating a stored function, not a stored procedure.  If you want to call a function

```
SELECT getOffer('xyz')
  INTO :myString
  FROM dual;
```

Remember as well that strings in SQL and PL/SQL are delimited by single quotes not double quotes.

Comment: Thanks Justin cave, i have one more question, in the java code i have use PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("/Standard.pdf"));
  when i use this jar in my local machine that time that pdf stored on local e: drive bcz my jar is there but if i put this RunnableJar.jar in oracle database on server so which location that pdf will stored ?

Comment: @SURJA - Assuming it works, it would appear to want to write to the root directory on the database server.  That's probably not what you want and unlikely to be something the DBA would allow.

Comment: Thanks Justin , i call the function using this but now he is giving following error    SELECT getOffer('xyz') INTO :myString FROM dual
                                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29540: class GetOffer does not exist      i uploaded jar using loadjava-force -thin -user username/password@Servername:PORT:SID -resolve RunnableFirstTest.jar      is there any thing that i need to change .

Comment: @SURJA - That sounds like a separate question.  We'd need to know how you built your JAR file and how you know that there is a `GetOffer` class in that JAR file.

Comment: I m using eclipse. please see the structure https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/?ui=2&ik=892c2aac14&view=att&th=13f517bb369b59ac&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_hi1gtxc20&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P-DJlX5uYf70sgDk3IpsR9f&sadet=1371470512603&sads=wMmKicXCHbA9rwyxzfKKfEbG3Ts&sadssc=1

Comment: i bult jar using eclipse export wizard > runnable jar >

Comment: @SURJA - Again, that sounds like a separate question.  Comments are not the place to try to debug completely separate issues.

Comment: please solve my problem bcz they are not allow me to ask more question..and this is urgent, please